# SQL Sqlalchemy Auto-increment of Primary key didnot work

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, sql-insert

when I ran `desc features`

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(128) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have table like below,

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | name                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 105314659 | latitude                                                 |
| 105314658 | final                                                    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I ran `INSERT INTO features (name) VALUES ('test')`, it didnot give auto-increment primary key, like

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | name                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 109728684 | test                                                     |
| 105314659 | latitude                                                 |
| 105314658 | final                                                    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id        | name                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 109728690 | test5                                                    |
| 109728688 | test4                                                    |
| 109728687 | test3                                                    |
| 109728686 | test2                                                    |
| 109728684 | test                                                     |
| 105314659 | latitude                                           |
| 105314658 | final                                                    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

anyone has any thoughts ? Thanks !

*** This table I constant `delete` and `insert` BTW. But when I ran single insert, it didnot auto incremental `id` ***

Comment: Did you look at the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE features;` ?  That should indicate the current auto_increment value.

Comment: Yes, i did. Thank you for pointing it out. It turns out that I had `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'test4' for key 'features.ix_features'` Error, and it consume the next AUTO_INCREMENT id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is from

`INSERT INTO nlp_request_feature_types (name) VALUES ('test4');` ,

It will cause `exc.IntegrityError`, like
`ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'test4' for key 'features.ix_features'`, BUT the id = 109728689 , will be allocated.

So when next run `INSERT INTO nlp_request_feature_types (name) VALUES ('test5');` , it will be successfully saved into table, and the primary key id = `109728690`.

As such, it will give us the illusion that `auto-incremental` primary key doesnot work. However, it does work, just because our mistake of `ERROR 1062` consumed one id.